# How to overcome the 2GB limit for a single column value in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I am ingesting json files where the entire data payload is on a single row, single column.
This column is an array of complex objects that I want to explode so that each object represents a row.
I'm using a Databricks notebook and spark.read.json() to load the file contents to a dataframe.
This results in a dataframe with a single row, and the data payload in a single column.(let's call it obj_array)
The problem I'm having is that the obj_array column is greater than 2GB so Spark cannot handle the explode() function.
Are there any alternatives to splitting the json file into more manageable chunks?
Thanks.
Code example...

```
#set path to file 
jsonFilePath='/mnt/datalake/jsonfiles/filename.json 

#read file to dataframe 
#entitySchema is a schema struct previously extracted from a sample file 

rawdf=spark.read.option("multiline","true").schema(entitySchema).format("json").load(jsonFilePath) 

#rawdf contains a single row of file_name,timestamp_created, and obj_array #obj_array is an array field containing the entire data payload (>2GB) 

explodeddf=rawdf.selectExpr("file_name","timestamp_created","explode(obj_array) as data") 
#this column explosion fails due to obj_array exceeding 2GB
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code that might help to understand what you are doing.

Comment: #set path to file
jsonFilePath='/mnt/datalake/jsonfiles/filename.json

#read file to dataframe
#entitySchema is a schema struct extracted from a sample file

rawdf = spark.read.option("multiline","true").schema(entitySchema).format("json").load(jsonFilePath)
#rawdf contains a signle row of file_name,timestamp_created, and obj_array
#obj_array is an array field containing the entire data payload (>2GB)

explodeddf=rawdf.selectExpr("file_name","timestamp_created","explode(obj_array) as data")
#this column explosion fails due to obj_array exceeding 2GB

Comment: apologies... that sample of code above has ended up very badly formatted... i'll add again without the comments

Comment: jsonFilePath='/mnt/datalake/jsonfiles/big_file.json

rawdf = spark.read.option("multiline","true").schema(entitySchema).format("json").load(jsonFilePath)

explodeddf=rawdf.selectExpr("file_name","timestamp_created","explode(obj_array) as data")

Comment: no help... why isn;t the line formatting from notepad retained when i paste into the comments box??

Comment: @Tinman you can edit the question and update it with your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you hit limits like this you need to re-frame the problem.  Spark is choking on 2Gigs in a column and that a pretty reasonable choke point.  Why not write your own [custom data reader](https://aamargajbhiye.medium.com/speed-up-apache-spark-job-execution-using-a-custom-data-source-fd791a0fa4b0).([Presenstation](https://databricks.com/session/apache-spark-data-source-v2)) That emits records in the way that you deem reasonable?  (Likely the best solution to leave the files as is.)
2. You could probably read all the records in with a simple text read and then "paint" in columns after.  You could use SQL tricks to try to expand and fill rows with windows/lag.
3. You could do file level cleaning/formatting to make the data more manageable for the out of the box tools to work with.